Не работают функции на кастомной странице
На главной странице сайта с wordpress я сделал форму с экшеном на кастомный php файл. Мне нужно, что бы при отправке данной формы пользователя сайта перебрасывало на страницу и выводило несколько позиций из интернет-магазина WooCommerce. Для этого я в php файле использовал wc_get_product(), но выходит ошибка, что такой функции нет. То же самое происходит если я пытаюсь добавить любой товар в корзину с помощью
$korzina = new WC_Cart();
$korzina->add_to_cart( 544 );

Хэдер тоже отобразиться не может, вылезает Call to undefined function get_header()
Как это исправить?

Потому что кастомный php файл ничего не знает о WordPress, а WordPress в свою очередь ничего не знает об этом кастомном php файле. Не знаю какую Вы решаете задачу, но я практически уверен, что можно просто создать страницу с соответствующим темплейтом под то что Вам нужно и выводить туда что угодно.

@Simon спасибо большое, разобрался!
